# General estimating equation with zero-inflated continuous data in R

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations, zero-inflation

I'm running a General Estimating Equation using the geepack package in R. I'm wondering what distribution family would be appropriate for my data, which are zero-inflated and continuous. I would have used the gamma distribution, but it appears that it cannot handle zeros. Also, it seems that the GEE in geepack cannot handle a Tweedie distribution, which also seemed like an appropriate distribution.

Comment: Indeed no continuous distribution really handles exact zeros, which is why you zero-inflate them.

Comment: From a theoretical point of view, there is often justification for the use of some distribution over another. What kind of data are you dealing with?

Answer (score 2):

Zero-inflated distributions are the product of two distributions, in my field it tends to be logistic and Poisson, but it could be something else.  Does the product of logistic and normal match your data?

Also, be sure that your data is zero inflated and not censored, the distinction is sometimes rather subtle, like in the case of women's wages.

Comment: Thanks for your response - do you know of a way to determine what two distributions might jointly describe my data? I'm wondering if there's a formal test I could try. And also if it is possible to specify a joint distribution in a GEE model

Comment: If your data is continuous as you say, I would expect logistic and normal, but you seem to be familiar with exotic distribution choices. I don't know if any formal test. I think I would start by making a QQ plot and choose from there.

Comment: If the data is the same, the good way to compare the best descriptive analytic form is an information criterion. AIC. AICc.  BIC.